# CakePHP hasOne relationship with different table

Tags: php, cakephp, relationship

Each `Artikel` has exactly one `Barcode`. For several reasons I want to split the `Artikel` model and the `Barcode` model. When I `find()` something from the artikel table it returns an array which contains the correct barcode section. But when I try to find a barcode, the array's artikel section is nulled.

This is what I mean:

```
// $this->Artikel->findById(102);
array(
    'Artikel' => array(
        'id' => '102',
        'name' => 'Spätburgunder Spätlese Barrique',
        'erzeuger_id' => '679',
        'volumen_id' => '44',
        'artikelgruppe_id' => '17'
    ),
    'Barcode' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'artikel_id' => '102',
        'barcode' => '123456'
    )
)

// $this->Barcode->findByBarcode(123456);
array(
    'Barcode' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'artikelnummer' => 'DE51076',
        'barcode' => '123456'
    ),
    'Artikel' => array(
        'artikelnummer' => null, // this is null
        'name' => null, // this is null as well
        'erzeuger_id' => null, // also null
        'volumen_id' => null, // ……
        'artikelgruppe_id' => null // null
    )
)
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

These are the models

```
// Barcode.php
public $hasOne = array(
    'Artikel' => array(
        'className' => 'Artikel',
        'foreignKey' => 'artikel_id'
    )
);


// Artikel.php
public $hasOne = array(
    'Barcode' => array(
        'className' => 'Barcode',
        'foreignKey' => 'artikel_id'
    )
);
```

Comment: I think you hav to write a belongsTo relationship from Barcode to Artickel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Article table - id, name, artikelgruppe_id and Barcode table - id, artikel_id, barcode

The correct way to relate these models is: Article hasOne Barcode and Barcode belongsTo Article

```
// Artikel.php
public $hasOne = array(
    'Barcode' => array(
        'className' => 'Barcode',
        'foreignKey' => 'artikel_id'
    )
);

// Barcode.php
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Artikel' => array(
        'className' => 'Artikel',
        'foreignKey' => 'artikel_id'
    )
);
```

Here `article_id` is in the Barcode table, so Article hasOne Barcode works as expected. Barcode hasOne Article would have worked if you had a `barcode_id` in your Article table.

But since you need the article from `article_id` field in Barcode table, you should use belongsTo relationship.

Comment: great, dude! that did it :)

Answer (score -1):

From what controller are you making those callings? If you are on the same model then is wrong because you must do the call through the references between the models. For example, I asume that you are in the `Artikel` model, so your first call is right, but the second one should be `$this->Artikel->Barcode->findById(1)`